# Facebook plugin: init not called with valid version

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I use phonegap build to create debug version for android.
I want to use facebook plugin.
In Config.xml I have

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.4.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="509210995889450" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="Food share" />
  </gap:plugin>
```

I use the file facebookConnectPlugin.js which is from the official plugin Github for facebook.
calling:

```
  facebookConnectPlugin.login([], success, fail);
```

I get:
Error: init not called with valid version
Error
    at Object. (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:37:148)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:588)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:550)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:550)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:550)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:550)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:550)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:550)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:550)
    at window.FB.require (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:15:550)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I tried to work with the official Phonegap plugin for facebook.
It seems Phonegap build uses another plugin, which doesn't use javascript facebookConnectPlugin, as is mentioned in their documentation. 
So I used 
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin
And they use https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/tree/962eb0a1c07935ff813e28aa9eaa5581f2e10416
And usage is different. Very confusing. Also makes it difficult if you try first to build on your desktop, and then it doesn't work on Phonegap Build.