# phonegap-facebook-plugin giving error :init not called with valid version

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I am using https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin in my application but when i giving error init not called with valid version.

```
Error
    at Object.a (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:61:150)
    at require (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:24:620)
    at require (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:24:584)
    at require (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:24:584)
    at require (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:24:584)
    at require (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:24:584)
    at require (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:24:584)
    at require (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:24:584)
    at __d (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:24:773)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js:72:1)
```

below is my config.xml for plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.8.0">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="<MyAppID>" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="<My_APP_NAME>" />
</gap:plugin>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202050/facebook-plugin-init-not-called-with-valid-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook plugin: init not called with valid version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202050/facebook-plugin-init-not-called-with-valid-version)